# BeautifulSoup, Scraping, get image size without being in the tags?

Tags: python, numpy, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

The Target: http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s9376368b43e8fd6a8025bfa284d8e732/e7c2/stock/vehicles/100/
I am 8 days into learning python, really love it. The target page is my old employer, to test my skills i want to write a python program that will daily check his stock and give me the changing results (sold, lowered prices ect.)

For me it is possible to get all the parameters i want, except the marker/trigger for the car being sold but not yet deleted from the page.

When you access the target page you see some of the images has the ribbon with "verkocht". I searched trough all the HTML and there is no trigger in the code for it to be sold or not, the CMS only changes the picture with a ribbon. I do noticed that the tumbnail changes size when this happens, so i wanted this to be my trigger.

Partial code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s9376368b43e8fd6a8025bfa284d8e732/e7c2/stock/vehicles/100/"
img_pre_url = "http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s4c74bf131813e9d7d3232b46224830a2"
getpage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(getpage.text, "html.parser")

for listingparse in soup.find_all("div", class_="row clearfix "):

    ftch_id = listingparse.get("id")[8:]

    ftch_imgurl = listingparse.find("div", class_="columnPhoto").img["src"]

    print("List id: "+ftch_id + "Image url: "+img_pre_url+ftch_imgurl)
```

Got this partial piece for demostrating this in the original one i write it to csv along with more parameters.

The End goal is to get variable 'sold_marker: V' for sold or 'sold_marker: X' for current listing

So what i as a noob think is i got 2 options.
1. Download the image and measure the size with numpy
2. Use some image processing lib and measure with the ugly green color if the ribbon is present.

How would you guys handle this? I hoped not to have to download the images everyday to measure this but i guess there is no alternative.

Comment: it seems images have size in its url - ie. `.../320x213/...` so you don't have to even download them.

Comment: Thanks furas, didn't notice that! That would be sufficient for my solution, i will leave the question because i am curious how to solve this puzzle for learning.

Comment: it is very popular to group images by size and use this size in folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image size is in its url so you can split url using `"/"` and get size from list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s9376368b43e8fd6a8025bfa284d8e732/e7c2/stock/vehicles/100/"
img_pre_url = "http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s4c74bf131813e9d7d3232b46224830a2"
getpage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(getpage.text, "html.parser")

for listingparse in soup.find_all("div", class_="row clearfix "):

    ftch_id = listingparse.get("id")[8:]
    ftch_imgurl = listingparse.find("div", class_="columnPhoto").img["src"]

    url_parts = ftch_imgurl.split('/')

    if url_parts[-2] == "260x195":
        verkocht = "verkocht"
    else:
        verkocht = ""

    print("List id:", ftch_id)
    print("Image url:", img_pre_url+ftch_imgurl)
    print("image size:", url_parts[-2], verkocht)
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
List id: 15668794
Image url: http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s4c74bf131813e9d7d3232b46224830a2/vehicle-images/15668794/1/1513180329/320x213/citroen-xsara-picasso-1-6i-attraction-zeer-ruime-gezinsauto
image size: 320x213 
---
List id: 15529833
Image url: http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s4c74bf131813e9d7d3232b46224830a2/vehicle-images/15529833/1/1512131899/260x195/dacia-logan-mcv-1-6-laureate-zeer-ruime-buitenkans
image size: 260x195 verkocht
---
List id: 15427090
Image url: http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s4c74bf131813e9d7d3232b46224830a2/vehicle-images/15427090/1/1510153600/320x213/fiat-punto-evo-1-3-m-jet-dynamic
image size: 320x213 
---
List id: 15287283
Image url: http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s4c74bf131813e9d7d3232b46224830a2/vehicle-images/15287283/1/1508421733/320x213/hyundai-matrix-1-6i-active-ek-2008-automaat-parkeersensoor-achter
image size: 320x213 
---
List id: 15218532
Image url: http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s4c74bf131813e9d7d3232b46224830a2/vehicle-images/15218532/1/1513263561/260x195/land-rover-range-rover-sport-3-6-tdv8-hse-vol-met-opties
image size: 260x195 verkocht
---
List id: 13888171
Image url: http://voorraadmodule.vwe-advertentiemanager.nl/s4c74bf131813e9d7d3232b46224830a2/vehicle-images/13888171/1/1491479399/320x213/maserati-quattroporte-4-7-s
image size: 320x213 
---
```